# Installing an application remotely

Tags: powershell, installation, parameter-passing

I'm trying to install software on a remote server. If I were to run it manually,

I would:

1. Run as Administrator
2. Choose 'Next' (on pop up)
3. Choose radio button 'Custom' install (vs. 'typical') Click 'Next'
4. Browse to install in specific folder (`$newFilePath`)
5. Click 'Next', click 'Install'

In my code, I don't understand how to choose the options of 'Custom' and choose my file path.
My arguments are not passing. The script will run, but won't install the software, let alone with the arguments. Any suggestions to successfully install with the needed arguments?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $targetServer -ScriptBlock {
    Start-Process -FilePath $app -ArgumentList "'$newFilePath'/silent /norestart'" -Verb runAs
}
```

Comment: You have to separate the arguments `-ArgumentList "$newFilePath", "/silent", "/norestart"`. It will be impossible to specify the custom path with a parameter if your app does not provide anything to set the new path, the default path will be used.

Comment: `$app` is the full path of the application.I'm copying the application from a shared drive and pasting it a 'Software' folder on the drive. But instead of installing the application in `Program Files (x86)` I want it in another directory (`$newFilePath`)

Comment: I edited my comment. If your app does not provide a parameter to change the installation path, you will not be able to change it.

Comment: How can I find if the app provides parameters?

Comment: I don't know your app so I can't say. Maybe by typing this in a cmd window : `yourapp.exe /?`

Comment: It literally depends entirely on the specific app and the specific installer. It could be as simple as the parameter being something like `-P installLocation=C:\some\other\directory` or something else. sometimes you get lucky and you can run the installer with the command `/?` or `/help` and it will give you the right parameter. Ultimately you will likely have to contact the app developer for more information.

Comment: Thank you, both of you helped. Luckily `/?` displays parameters.